# What is the base url for bot connector API

Tags: botframework

I am trying to send messages from my bot to a conversation and i need to know the base url for sending the /v3/conversations/activities

Comment: Have you even tried googling the URL "/v3/conversations"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the channel.

https://kik.botframework.com/api/V3...

https://slack.botframework.com/api/V3...

https://skype.botframework.com/api/V3...

etc.